# Do I have to initialize the CPU registers in assembly code that is called from C?

Tags: c, assembly, initialization, nasm, cpu-registers

I'm reading Paul Carter's [pcasm](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/) book. It uses NASM, a C driver app that calls my assembly code, and a companion library that makes it easy to do basic I/O in assembly.

This is what my function that will be called from C looks like:

```
segment .text
    global  _asm_main
_asm_main:
    enter   0,0               ; setup routine
    pusha

    mov bx, 0034h   ; bx = 52 (stored in 16 bits)
    mov cl, bl      ; cl = lower 8-bits of bx
    mov eax, ecx
    call print_int

    popa
    mov     eax, 0            ; return back to C
    leave                     
    ret
```

The `print_int` function prints the value store at `eax` as an integer. But this prints out garbage to stdout:

```
4200244
```

If I initialize the **ecx** register to 0 with `mov ecx, 0000h` before using it, I will get the expected output:

```
52
```

Is initialization always required, and if so, is there a quick way of initializing all the registers to 0 (or a user-defined initializer), from either C or NASM?

I'm using XP32, MinGW 4.4.0, and NASM 2.09.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `print_int` prints out the value of `eax`. In your code you only assign to the lowest of the four bytes of `eax` (a.k.a. `al`) via the following chain of assignments: `bl`->`cl`->`al`. The remaining three bytes of `eax` are left uninitialized. Your code inherits whatever values happened to be in those three bytes at the start of your routine. This is why you get garbage.

You have to initialize all the registers and memory locations that you use.

My x86 assembly is a bit rusty, but I am pretty sure there isn't a single instruction that would set all general-purpose registers to zero. If you were so inclined, you could probably write a macro that would do this for you.

Comment: I guess ASM programmers/compilers initialize only registers that they're going to use. I would initialize all of them at once since I'm strictly interested in learning ASM right now, and I'd like to avoid bugs like these. I'm not planning on writing any big amount of ASM code, but I do want to understand how a language like C works at a lower level. Thanks.

Comment: Fair enough. Since this is only a learning exercise, one low-tech way would be to copy-and-paste a bunch of `mov` instructions at the start of every function you write.

Comment: I've learned something new today, and I think it might be relevant to comment on this. The `PUSHA` instruction in my code (which gets replaced with `PUSHAD` by NASM) pushes all register values to the stack in one order. Now I am responsible to initialize the registers to my own values. Before my function returns, I can call `POPA` (which gets replaced with `POPAD`), which pops doublewords from the stack to the registers in the reverse order of `PUSHAD`. So I need not worry about losing previous data from the registers.

Comment: @AndrejMitrović:  You don't need to zero all the registers; just use `movzx eax, cl` if you want a zero-extending move.  Only merge into the low byte of a full register if that's what you *want*, or maybe sometimes if nothing will read the full register.  That's of course not the case when you call `print_int` which *does* read the full EAX.  You don't need `enter` or `pusha`, just follow the calling convention's rules like that EBX is call-preserved.  `pusha` / `popa` is a slow way to make sure you don't step on the caller's registers, though.  (Separate issue from not reading garbage)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's required.

Nothing is done for you, in assembly.
You have to initialize every register the way you want it.